# How do I sort in numerical order, the items in a to-many relationship?

Tags: ios, swift, sorting, realm, relationship

I have 2 models (a "Category" model  and an "Item" model) such as following.
“Category” has a to-many relationship to “Item” via the property “items”

I would like to get the sorted data of “category” and “item” by its "order" but how can I do it?

- Category.swift

  ```
  import Foundation
  import RealmSwift

  class Category: Object {
      @objc dynamic var name: String = ""
      @objc dynamic var order: Int = 0  //　use this for sorting
      let items = List<Item>
  }
  ```
- Item.swift

  ```
  import Foundation
  import RealmSwift

  class Item: Object {
      @objc dynamic var name: String = ""
      @objc dynamic var order: Int = 0  // use this for sotging
      let category = LinkingObjects(fromType: Category.self, property: "items")   
  }
  ```

I can only sort the ‘’category’’ by its order but I can’t do it with the ‘’items’’

```
let categories = realm.objects(Category.self).sorted(byKeyPath: "order", ascending: true)
```

[image: What I want to do]

Comment: The question is a bit unclear. The Category object has an `items` list - how would you sort the categories by another list. Suppose Category A has a List of D and F. Category B has a List of C and Z. How would that sort work? C comes before D but F comes before Z. Can you clarify what your trying to do or pehaps even include an example *in the question* of what results you are looking for?

Comment: I added aa photo on my post to better explain what I want to accomplish

I am making a grocery list app. 
First I have a category. The categories are vegetables, meats,
Fruits etc. Then for every category name, there is an assigned number for its order. 
For each category name, there is a specific list for it. 
So for example, in the Vegetable category, there is an item list of different vegetables like carrots, eggplant etc.
For each item, there is a corresponding number for its order.
So for example, carrots is 1, eggplant is 2, potato is 3 and so on.

Comment: What I want to accomplish is to be able to show the categories, and items by its proper numerical order.

So for example:
For category…
If vegetable is 2, fruits is 3 and meat is 1
I want it to show up like this….

Meat                 1
Vegetable         2
Fruits                3

I also want to do the same for the items of each category

For example:

eggplant is 2, potato is 3, carrots is 1
I want it to show up like this…

Carrots         1
Eggplant       2
Potato           3

I was able to go it for the “category” but I couldn’t do it for the items list.

Comment: I looked at your screen shot and it's still unclear what kind of ordering you are expecting on your items. I see onion and tomato are ordered fist but why are they listed before orange and apple? In other words, if Meat is the first category then why aren't chicken and pork listed first in the items list? This goes back to what I was asking in my first comment - what's the purpose of ordering the items and how do you determine what that order is? e.g. meats first, then vegetables then fruits? Or something else?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake on the picture I posted before but I replaced it with a fixed one now. I just want them to show up listed by numerical order in the tableview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really aren't too far off.

Realm Results objects can be unordered so it's important to have a strategy to keep Results objects loaded in the order you want. As is, you've got that on your category objects with this

```
@objc dynamic var order: Int = 0  //　use this for sorting
```

On the other hand, Realm **List** objects MAINTAIN their order of insertion

```
class Category: Object {
    let items = List<Item>
```

So if chicken was added to a category items list, and then pork, that order will stick; chicken at index 0, pork at index 1.

```
Meat
   chicken
   pork
```

That's covered in the [Realm Documentation](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#many-to-one)

> List properties are guaranteed to preserve their order of insertion.

Because of that, when populating a tableView as in the question, you can use the tableView titleForHeaderInSection to get the section names (Categories: Meat, Vegetables, Fruit) from the results object (because they were ordered when the results were loaded from Realm)

Then for the rows within each section, you can read the Category->items List for the items, which will be ordered by their insertion because they are in a List.

For completeness, here's the code for handling the section of a tableView

```
//
//handle sections
//
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return self.yourCategoryResults.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    let title = self.yourCategoryResults[section].name //the section title
    return title
}
```

and then the code to handle the rows in each section

```
//
//handleTableView rows
//
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let rowsInSection = self.yourCategoryResults[section].items.count
    return rowsInSection
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellReuseIdentifier", for: indexPath)
    let item = self.yourCategoryResults[indexPath.section].items[indexPath.row]
    let text = item.name
    cell.textLabel?.text = text
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering! I could solve my problem because of the information you gave me. Thanks again!